# How to display sum of particular column from Array of Object which is having dynamic columns using Angularjs dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, dynamic

How to display sum of particular column from Array of Object which is having dynamic columns using Angularjs dynamically[Dynamic Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASwyy.png)
Earning Columns and deductions heads will be dynamic ..

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {

   $scope.employeeSalaryslipDetails=
   [
    { 
      "earningresult":
       [{

                hrmeD_Name : 'Basic Pay',
                        hresD_Amount : 15000

            }, {

                hrmeD_Name : 'DA',
                         hresD_Amount : 7500

            },{

                hrmeD_Name : 'HRA',
                         hresD_Amount : 1600

            },{

                hrmeD_Name : 'TA',
                        hresD_Amount : 3000

            }]
    },
    {
     "deductionresult":
      [{

                hrmeD_Name : 'Basic Pay',
                        hresD_Amount : 15000

            }, {

                hrmeD_Name : 'DA',
                         hresD_Amount : 7500

            },{

                hrmeD_Name : 'HRA',
                         hresD_Amount : 1600

            },{

                hrmeD_Name : 'TA',
                        hresD_Amount : 3000

            }]
    }
  ]; 
      
   $scope.earningheadlist = $scope.employeeSalaryslipDetails[0].earningresult;

                                   

 

                                    $scope.earnlen = $scope.earningheadlist.length;
                                  
 
            
});
})(window.angular);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngRepeat-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
  
  <table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Sl.No</th>
  
  <th colspan="{{earnlen}}">Earnings</th>
  <th rowspan="2">Gross Earning</th>
 
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th ng-repeat="earncolumn in earningheadlist">{{earncolumn.hrmeD_Name}}</th>
  <th ng-repeat="dedcolumn in deductionheadlist">{{dedcolumn.hrmeD_Name}}</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeSalaryslipDetails">
  <td></td>
  
  <td ng-repeat="earn in employee.earningresult">{{earn.hresD_Amount | number : 2}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.grossEarning | number : 2}}</td>
  
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
 <tr>
  <td> Total</td>
  <td ng-repeat="earncolumn in earningheadlist">{{TotalEarningHead()}}</td>
  <td>{{TotalgrossEarning() | number : 2}}</td>
 
 </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
  
        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Earning Heads having dynamic columns and for particular column ,
need a some of that particular column dynamically

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: In HTML ,I tried the above code, But for dynamic columns i am not able to get the sum

Comment: Hi ,kindly see my latest code

Comment: Did you include the code of `TotalEarningHead()` and `TotalgrossEarning()`?

Comment: Only for TotalgrossEarning() ,i have return a function.. here it is..   $scope.TotalgrossEarning = function () {
            var total = 0;
            if ($scope.employeeSalaryslipDetails != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employeeSalaryslipDetails.length; i++) {


                    var product = $scope.employeeSalaryslipDetails[i];
                    total += product.grossEarning;
                }
            }

            return total;
        }